# How to use the key datatype and localization in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I am trying to create a custom field in `biblatex` of type `key`

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=key]{myfield}
```

Based on my understanding of the documentation

> Key fields May hold printable data or localisation keys. A test is performed to determine whether the value of the field is a known localisation key (the localisation keys defined by default are listed in §4.9.2). If so, the localised string is printed. If not, the value is printed as is. A typical example is the type
>   field.

if `myfield` has a value of `editortr` and the language is english, I should get `editor and translator` (or maybe `ed. and trans.`). But that is not what I see. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo,
  myfield = {editortr}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=key]{myfield}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
  \printlist{language}%
}{%
  \printlist{language}%
  \printfield{myfield}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The log tells me it found `english.lbx`

> Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
>   Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

Comment: I'm not really sure here and don't have much time to look better at the moment. But take a look at `biblatex.def`, where you'll find, eg. `\DeclareFieldFormat{type}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}` or the bibmacros `authorstrg`/`editorstrg`. You'll notice the test is done there, and not by some inner mechanisms. And `ifbibstring` (or variants) is used for the purpose.

Comment: Tested: `\DeclareFieldFormat{myfield}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}` gets the job done.

Comment: @gusbrs but then why use `key` and not `literal`. The documentation makes it sound like it should work out of the box.

Comment: Good question, perhaps a useful standard? (I'm guessing here). Anyway, in `biblatex.def` you see how the "effect" is actually implemented, as far as I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted passage from the documentation is slightly misleading. It suggests that the backend (BibTeX/Biber) performs the test to determine if the given value is a localisation string and it also suggests that this happens automatically. Both of these are not true

1. Your average key field is handled exactly like a literal field by Biber and BibTeX. Indeed the data output in the `.bbl` is exactly the same for literal and key datatypes. (I remember that Biber would remap `langid` fields from BCP 47 to `babel` identifiers and and I can [still see part of that in the Biber source](https://github.com/plk/biber/blob/a3677f6eeae54f9e0cf6aa738931fad897eef449/lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm#L983-L992), but I failed to produce an example where that worked as I expected... Anyway, that is hard-coded behaviour for one field.)
2. The difference between literal and key fields or list only manifests itself when their format is declared on the `biblatex` end. Literal types are just printed as-is, whereas key types usually have declarations like

   ```
   \DeclareFieldFormat{type}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}
   ```

   Which implements the behaviour from the quoted passage, but on the `biblatex` side. **This has to be done explicitly in the field format.** It does not happen automatically even if the field was declared to be of datatype key.

That means that you need

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{myfield}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}
```

in your example.

I have opened a ticket at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/839 to discuss changes to the documentation, so that the behaviour is clearly documented in the future. Suggestions are very welcome.